# Schema Config with Custom Input

Tags: content-management-system, sanity

So I am working on a multi-stage select input in Sanity.

```
 {
      name: 'home',
      title: 'Home',
      type: 'object',
      fields: [
        {
          name: 'team',
          title: 'Team',
          type: 'object',
          components: {
            input: CustomSelect,
          }
        }
      ]
}
```

I am specifying the Team type as Object since in the Custom Component and the value is an object:

```
{
 fooValue: {...},
 fooValue2: {...}
}
```

However I am running into this issue:
`The "fields" property must be an array of fields. Instead saw "undefined"`

I tried changing the type to string, which worked but the type was different and pushed the validation type error. As seen in the image below. So that is why initially the type was set to object. However it does not work as intended, pushed Sanity Errors.

[Value error: Value is object, expected string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX5T8.png)

What steps do you think I should take?